# Getting descriptive outcomes from ExePathAction

Tags: ros, navigation, teb-local-planner, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to design some recovery behaviors for a bot following a set of waypoints, with velocities issued by TEB. I am using ExePathAction to start the navigation with TEB.

I would like to know when the path is blocked (BLOCKED_PATH = 109) in order to trigger either a GetPathAction until the next waypoint, or maybe some other recovery behaviour.

Are the descriptive outcomes + messages already implemented in MBF? Or do these descriptive outcomes have to be implemented in the controller (in this case: TEBLocalPlannerROS)?
Or should it be implemented by extending some function of the controller_action or abstract_controller_execution?

Thank you for your time, any help will be appreciated! :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/323207/getting-descriptive-outcomes-from-exepathaction/) by [curi_ROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/37504/curi_ros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 166 on 2019-05-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, MBF just provides extended interfaces for the plugins, with error code and message. But it's up the the plugins to provide this information. If a plugin doesn't implement the extended MBF, we wrap the old nav_core interface and report SUCCESS / FAILURE depending on there it returns true / false.

For TEB, we have implemented MBF's extended interface in [our fork](https://github.com/magazino/teb_local_planner/tree/mbf_plugin). We report the following possible outcomes:

- SUCCESS
- NOT_INITIALIZED
- INTERNAL_ERROR
- INVALID_PATH
- NO_VALID_CMD

To my understanding, TEB doesn't recognizes explicitly situations when BLOCKED_PATH outcome makes sense, but feel free to PR it if you have already implemented the code!

---

Originally posted by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) with karma: 2284 on 2019-05-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [curi_ROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/37504/curi_ros/) on 2019-05-15**:
We don't have any code for the BLOCKED_PATH event yet, but this helps. Thank you!

**Comment by [artemiialessandrini](https://answers.ros.org/users/36583/artemiialessandrini/) on 2020-07-02**:
people?
@curi_ROS